# Cloned div is different from the original

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a search feature for a smartphone app. It identifies the div containing the searched for term and appends it to an empty search results div. This is working fine. I'm trying to prevent multiple identical search results being displayed, this generally works but creates one duplicate search result.

It looks like the cloned and original text is different I've set up a jsfiddle here 
    http://jsfiddle.net/tonybabb/2mwr3hp2/3/ illustrating the problem.

Html:

```
<div id="originalText">
some text
</div>
<div id = "copiedText">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var $originalText = $("#originalText").text();
$("#originalText").clone(true, true).appendTo("#copiedText");
if ("$originalText".match($("#copiedText").text())) {
    alert("Theyre the same");
} else {
    alert("Theyre different");   
}
```

I have been working on this for several days now, I'd really appreciate some advice. Thanks.

Comment: `"$originalText"` is a string. You are comparing `"$originalText"` to `"some text"`

Answer (score 2):

You're not matching the text, you're checking if the literal string `"$originalText"` matches `$('#copiedText').text()`

Also, look at the rendered HTML, this is copying the whole div into the other div, not just the text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do the following,

1.remove quotes from `"$originalText"`
 2. You should use `$("#copiedText").find("div").text()`, since the cloned div is attached to `$("#copiedText")`

```
var $originalText = $("#originalText").text();
$("#originalText").clone(true, true).appendTo("#copiedText");
if ($originalText.match($("#copiedText").find("div").text())) {
        alert("Theyre the same");
}
else {
 alert("Theyre different");   
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mwr3hp2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need the clone, so that possibly event-handler are staying attached but here is another approach, which is working:

```
var $originalText = $("#originalText").text();
$("#copiedText").append($("#originalText").html());
if ($originalText.match($("#copiedText").text())) {
    alert("Theyre the same");
} else {
    alert("Theyre different");
}
```

In this solution, only the containing html is copied to the other div.

Furthermore: Your variable `$originalText` is containing a string already, so you don't have to put that in quotes to compare it via `.match()`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bvt66sg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the quotes around `"$originalText"`. Second, it doesn't work because of the line breaks in your html. The following works:

```
<div id="originalText">some text</div>
<div id="copiedText"></div>
```